# Event listener in ios app

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, nsnotificationcenter

I am new in iOS development. 
I learnt about Delegate (Single Observer) and also `NSNotificationCenter` to listen to event.

Now I want to pop up an alert view when an event in a manager class happens. May I know if there's a way to pop it up regardless which view controller is showing? From my understanding, `NSNotificationCenter` allows me to show a alert but I have to implement the show up method on each of the view controller class. Is it a better way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You could always have the AppDelegate listen for the event and display the alert - it is always there in the background no matter what view controller is displayed.

Comment: @Michael You still need to find the top-most view controller so you can present the `UIAlertController` from it.

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` does not allow you to show an alert. It simply allows you to post and receive notifications. What you do when you receive a notification is completely separate. If you want to show a `UIAlertController`, that is fine but it has nothing to do with `NSNotificationCenter` at that point.

Comment: could use a base class that all your viewcontrollers inherit from, then only need to implement in one place

Comment: Thank you @Fonix I kind of like this answer and I will try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on implement it at AppDelegate. Would you mind sharing with me some solutions if I have to walk away from AppDelegate as I am going to make it a pod package than a standalone app. Thank you :D @Michael

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show up a native alert view, you can use AppDelegate class as a listener to NSNotoficationCenter, because native alert view will be added to top window directly.

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "native alert view"?

Comment: Native alert view, I refer to UIAlertView or UIAlertController (iOS8+).

Comment: `UIAlertController` doesn't automatically get added to the top window directly. You must present it from the top-most view controller. And `UIAlertView` shouldn't be used except in iOS 7 or earlier.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I got it wrong for UIAlertController.

Comment: Could I know if Singleton class works as I have to remove AppDelegate as I am going to make it a pod package later on and have to remove it .

Comment: what kind of class do you want to make a singleton class? you shouldn't make a singleton a UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worry about the fact to implement your alert in every controller, you shouldn't.
They are many ways to solve that issue, you could for instance :

- Subclass UIViewController, and implement a method inside that will display your alert. Just keep in mind that everytime you'll use a `UIViewController`, use your subclassed controller instead.
- You could use protocols (objective C) or extensions (swift), to add a function that will display your alert view. In that case you don't even need to subclass anything :
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Also don't forget that in swift, any properties can be listened natively. For instance, when you set your property you can do this :

```
var myProperty : String {
    willSet {
      doSomething()
    }
    didSet {
      presentMyAlertController()
    }
}
```

Comment: None of this really applies to what the OP is asking. It sounds like there will be one (maybe more) event manager class. It is only that class that needs to display an alert. No view controller needs to know or care.

Comment: Right, but if it's a manager it's not a controller, so how to show that alert then? Make an extension of UIViewController will allow to display an alert everywhere, no matter the controller displayed right?

Comment: No. The event manager can determine the top most view controller and present a `UIAlertController` from there. At least that's one way.

Comment: Yep that's one way indeed! For me managers shouldn't take care of the UI, but it depends on people :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice on implement it at AppDelegate. Would you mind sharing with me some solutions if I have to walk away from AppDelegate as I am going to make it a pod package than a standalone app. Thank you :D